# Работа с курсором в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, процедуры

Здравствуйте. Написал процедуру (FUNCTION в терминах СУБД PostgreSQL). Возвращает курсор с записями. Как пишется SQL-скрипт, выводящий хоть что-то из этого курсора (в консоль стандартной утилиты pgsql, в графической утилите pgAdmin и т.д.). Проще, говоря, как дальше работать с этим курсором на вывод записей. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. А работа как с обычной таблицей не идёт?
типа `select * from fun(par);`?

Comment: Ну вот моя функция, которая собралась и подтвердилась СУБД. Вот произвожу её вызов
    select *from workers_by_spec('Дизайнер');
И получаю в Панели вывода pgAdmin'a следующее:
таблицу с одной колонкой "workers_by_spec refcursor" и одной записью: 
    <unnamed portal 1>.